# Might "equivocal" be applied to our scientific understandings?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

I just read the question and answers about the meaning of "equivocal".  Might "equivocal" be used to describe the wave and particle appreciations of light?  The results of all inquiries and investigations that continue to be lit by doubt?

Comment: Yes, 'equivocal' can be used instead of 'contradictory' or 'ambiguous'; it has a bit of an metaphorical feel, like the facts themselves have agency and are trying to confuse you intentionally. However '_scientific understandings_' is an incorrect usage. Use 'scientific knowledge'. 'Understandings' and 'teachings' may be used commonly in Indian English, but sounds 'off' in AmE.

Comment: In US science, we'd say "views" instead of "appreciations", but that's just local dialect. And, yes, you could say that the wavicle was an equivocal phenomenon, since it manifests some properties of a wave and some of a particle. Just like _that_ in relative clauses like _that continue to be lit by doubt_ manifests some of the properties of a referential pronoun and some properties of a complementizer; _that_ is an equivocal word.

Answer (score 1):

It is a word which is used more frequently in the negative, as 'unequivocal', meaning unambiguous, unwavering, certain, clear-cut, incontrovertible etc.

As such it is a word which, for some odd reason, I might feel a little shy of using in the positive. But that is not to say it is wrong or that others will not feel differently.

There are however a host of alternatives as any thesaurus will indicate.